# Magento 2 add product to cart programmatically with custom options

Tags: php, magento2

I have created one test script file for add product into cart **with custom options**. I want display selected custom option of product in cart using programmatically.

Please check my below code:

```
$productId = 25;
$product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$cart = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');  
$params = array();      
$params['options[469]'] = 459;
$params['qty'] = 1;
$params['product'] = 25

$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
```

Using objectmanager i have created cart and product object. When i have fired this script in browser, it's show me error:

> Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Please specify
>   product's required option(s).

I have already passed custom option in params array. but still it's show error.

**How can i add product into cart with selected custom options ?**

Please help me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have got the solution of this problem.
Here is my updated code.

```
$productId = 127;
$product = $obj->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

$cart = $obj->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');    
$params = array();      
$options = array();
$params['qty'] = 1;
$params['product'] = 127;

foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) 
{       
    foreach ($o->getValues() as $value) 
    {
        $options[$value['option_id']] = $value['option_type_id'];

    }           
}

$params['options'] = $options;
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
```

This code is work for me.

Comment: Where do you put this code? i am using a custom module for creating custom products (adding frame etc on image) and adding the code in the same file, and redirecting to cart after that. It is giving me error that memory is exhausted even if i increase the limit to 2GB. i am able to create my custom product in backend as configurable product but not able to add this to cart in the process. should i add this code on cart page? please suggest !

Answer (score 5):

please replace your code :

```
$productId = 25;
$product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$cart = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');  
$params = array();      
$params['options[469]'] = 459;
$params['qty'] = 1;
$params['product'] = 25

$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
```

Replace with

```
$productId = 25;
$product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
$cart = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');  
$formKey = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey')->getFormKey();  
$option = array('469'=>459);

$params = array(
                    'form_key' => $formKey,
                    'product' => $productId, //product Id
                    'qty'   =>1, //quantity of product                
                    'options' => $option
                    );
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
```